# How can I access the data generated by autocorrelation_plot?

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I plotted the autocorrelation line using the function `autocorrelation_plot` in Pandas and would like to access the data it generates.

I am basically trying to find out (locate) the lag points in my dataset.

How can this be achieved?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = np.array(range(5)) * 10

ax = pd.plotting.autocorrelation_plot(data)
```

[image]

`ax` is an `AxesSubplot`

```
<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x7f8b52758470>
```

which has an attribute called `lines`

```
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f8b51c30f28>,
 <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f8b51c39390>,
 <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f8b51c397b8>,
 <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f8b51c39ba8>,
 <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f8b51c39f98>,
 <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f8b51c423c8>]
```

If you now loop through these:

```
for li in ax.lines:
    print(li.get_xydata())
```

you obtain

```
[[0.         1.15194588]
 [1.         1.15194588]]
[[0.         0.87652254]
 [1.         0.87652254]]
[[0. 0.]
 [1. 0.]]
[[ 0.         -0.87652254]
 [ 1.         -0.87652254]]
[[ 0.         -1.15194588]
 [ 1.         -1.15194588]]
[[ 1.   0.4]
 [ 2.  -0.1]
 [ 3.  -0.4]
 [ 4.  -0.4]
 [ 5.   0. ]]
```

So, as we can see:

```
xydata = ax.lines[-1].get_xydata()

array([[ 1. ,  0.4],
       [ 2. , -0.1],
       [ 3. , -0.4],
       [ 4. , -0.4],
       [ 5. ,  0. ]])
```

If you want the data separately, you can do:

```
xdata = ax.lines[-1].get_xdata()
# array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

ydata = ax.lines[-1].get_ydata()
# array([ 0.4, -0.1, -0.4, -0.4,  0. ])
```